# How do I take the URL of the webpage I am on and make it into a variable?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save a javascript variable that is text inside the URL of the page I am editing.

The URL looks like this:

file...    ...?=&username=Sarah_Wesley

I can't just copy it and save it because the text after '=&username=' will be different for different users and I would like to get this text out.

I'm also open to any other suggestions you have for extracting the username that are less messy than this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location.search object. You'll get all the info within it.